# Calling a function into main declared inside one class, but unable to

Tags: python, function, class, object, program-entry-point

I am calling a function - kindle into main function both declared inside a class, and i am instantiating the object of the class inside main and then trying to access kindle with it, but i am unable to. The error shows as : NameError: name 'Program' is not defined.

```
class Program:

   def kindle():
      x = 2
      return x

   def main():
      p = Program()
      p.kindle()
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Comment: What means you are unable to access the function? What happens, what should happen?

Comment: apologies sir, the errors shows as : NameError: name 'Program' is not defined

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Some suggestions: 1. add a colon after the class name. 2. add self as a parameter for kindle method. 3. unindent both main function and if block. 4. There will be still no output thou.

Comment: First problem is that function definition of "main" and the following "if" should be after the class, not in it. The indentation must be changed.

Comment: @oldwooki yes colon is there i just forgot to put it here, i simplified the problem actually into this snippet

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you sir, it was defined inside the class. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Since main() calling Program, the source looks incorrect.
It should be

```
class Program:

   def kindle():  # bad
      x = 2
      return x

def main():
   p = Program()
   p.kindle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Also `kindle` definition should be either

```
@staticmethod
def kindle():
```

or `def kindle(self):`